# Heat Transfer on boiling water

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity, convection, heat-conduction

Let's say I'll boil water on the stove from 25°C to 100°C, what heat transfer happens? Is it conduction (heat warms up the pot), or is it convection (causes water molecules to move away from the interior of the pot as they are replaced by cooler molecules), or both? Thanks

Comment: It is, of course, both.

Comment: Note - all 3 heat transfer mechanisms (e.g., convection, conduction, and radiation) are normally happening at the same time, but we tend to focus on only one at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Heat transfer through the pot is by conduction. Heat transfer from the surface of the pot to the water, as well as heat transfer within the water, is a combination of conduction and convection.

Hope this helps.